# Is there a way to get logs from a react native app that is in production?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, logging, production

I'm currently making an expo react native app. Is it possible for a production build to send logs over the internet to me whenever an error occurs? The idea is to create a button that just sends the logs over whenever the app fails/has a bug.

Additionally, this has to be a safe enough solution so that the customers cannot just access all the logs.

I looked into cloud logging with firebase crashlytics but is there a way to accomplish this without the cloud using expo/react native?

Comment: I think I just found my answer with https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-file-logger.